# Как нарисовать круг при помощи класса js?

Tags: javascript, ооп, классы, функции

Нужно нарисовать круг при помощи класса js,не выходит

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<style>
.square {
  position: absolute;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: lightyellow;
}
.circle{
  border-radius:50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50;
  height: 50;
}
</style>
<div class="square" >
</div>
<script>
class Ball { 
  constructor(x,y,xSpeed,ySpeed,color,kvadrat){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
  this.ySpeed = ySpeed;
  this.color=color;
  this.kvadrat=kvadrat;
  }
  Circle (){
  this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
  this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
  this.xSpeed = -2;
  this.ySpeed = 3;
   let div = document.createElement('div');
   kvadrat.div.className = "circle";
   div.style.top =y + 'px';
   div.style.left =x+'px'; 
   kvadrat.append(div);
   return kvadrat;
  }
}
let ball = new Ball();
ball.Circle();
```

Comment: во 1-х - у класса Ball, нету метода Click, во 2-х - при вызове класса Ball вы не передаете никаких параметров в конструктор, в 3-х - Circle должен быть отдельным классом а не методом класса Ball, в 4-х - что такое kvadrat, где он объвялен?

Comment: Исправила,непонятен момент с прорисовкой в функции и передачей параметров

Answer (score 4):

можно так

```js
class Circle {
  constructor(node, radius) {
    this.node = node;

    if (!this.node)
      throw new Error('Missing node parametr.');

    this.radius = radius || 100;

    this._init();
  }

  _init() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 2 * this.radius; i++) {
      let height = Math.abs(this.radius - i);
      let chord = 2 * Math.sqrt(this.radius * this.radius - height * height);

      let layout = document.createElement('div');
      layout.style.height = '1px';
      layout.style.width = `${chord}px`;

      this.node.appendChild(layout);
    }
  }
}

const node = document.querySelector('.container');
const radius = 200;

new Circle(node, radius);
```

```css
.container div {
  background: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Другой вариант,конечно,хорошо,но хотелось бы доработать свой вариант